# Android studio Firebase authentication

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

im making an android studio application in which there will be two users one driver and user , but im facing a problem user can sign in in driver page and same with driver too can anyone help me please

Comment: Refer to this. https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/start